# Are South Australian Electoral Rolls available to search online anywhere?

Tags: south-australia, australia

Ancestry.com has an [**Australian Electoral Rolls, 1903-1980**](http://search.ancestry.com.au/search/db.aspx?dbid=1207) database that "contains selected Australian electoral rolls, with the exception of South Australia, that run from 1903-1980".

I'm not sure why South Australia is the exception and am hoping that these may be available online elsewhere.  So far my Google searches have only uncovered hardcopies and microfiches.

Does anyone know if they are already available online or, if not, whether there are any efforts currently underway to make this the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

South Australian Electoral Rolls are not available on-line. Selected rolls are available via look-up, micr-fiche and hard copies. To find which are available, see the details on Adelaide ProFormat, http://www.jaunay.com/electoral.html.